# I can't change the postgres user password

Tags: postgresql

First a question:

I am a complete newbie. Is it correct that postgresql installs with some default passwords without asking to change it during installation? What are those passwords? I am just playing with an app and if I know the default passwords, everything will be okay.

As you could tell I don't have the default passwords. Somewhere I read that postgres user allows login with no password. Do I then leave the password field in the app config file empty?

I used the following command from the postgresql command line:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

I get the following error:

```
ALTER: command not found.
```

Could you tell me what is going on?

I have postgresql 11.6 & 12.1.

Comment: what was the "postgresql command line" that you used? `psql`?

Comment: Also, "Is it correct that postgresql installs with some default passwords without asking to change it during installation?" -- It depends on how you installed it.  If you used `yum` or `apt`, then there may not be a password, depending on how you invoked `initdb`.  If you used some prepackaged installer, you may have been asked to type in a password before postgres was installed

Comment: You apparently did not run that inside `psql` but from a operating system command line

Comment: I cannot log in to psql. It says authentication failed. I am on the local machine. This is strange.

Comment: psql --version says 12.1 but postgresql or posgres --version return error: command not found.

Answer (score 0):

For a newly installed PostgreSQL cluster, it does not allow non-local connections, namely that you can connect it locally without a password. For example:

```
psql -U postgres -p5432 -h127.0.0.1 -d postgres
```

You can run `psql --help` to see all the help information for psql.

As above, after you log in, you can create a new user and specify a password[1] or change the password like you do.

Note that you can't log in to the database with this account on other hosts if you don't modify the client authentication configuration file[2].

> Client authentication is controlled by a configuration file, which traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and is stored in the database cluster's data directory. (HBA stands for host-based authentication.) A default pg_hba.conf file is installed when the data directory is initialized by initdb. It is possible to place the authentication configuration file elsewhere, however; see the hba_file configuration parameter.

#### References

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: I cannot log in to psql with the command provided. It says authentication failed. I haven't touched the configuration file. By the way I am on an Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: If you install the instance with your host username, the database cluster default username will be your host username, so try `psql -p5432 -h127.0.0.1 -d postgres` or `psql postgres`

Answer (score 0):

Unless your installation process sets one, the superuser `postgres` has no password set. You connect from the local computer without a password, then you can set one.

First, start the command line client:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then you can run your `ALTER ROLE` command.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to changing PostgreSQL database user (postgres) password:

1. Log in as Linux / Ubuntu PostgreSQL admin user onto Linux / Ubuntu:

su - postgres

2. And then you can ALTER ROLE:

ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';